# Strange behavior with OpenCL - CPU output doesnt match even with single thread GPU output

Tags: opencl

I am trying to run the following piece of LUDecomposition code in an OpenCL kernel.
'A' below is a single precision floating point array.

```
for( k = 0; k < N; k++ ) 
{
  for(j=k+1; j < N; j++)    {
      A[k * N + j] = A[k * N + j] / A[k * N + k]; 
  }

  for(i=k+1; i < N; i++)    {
    for (j=k+1; j < N; j++)   { 
      A[i * N + j] = A[i * N + j] - (A[i * N + k] * A[k * N + j]); 
    }
  }
}
```

I am running this code on the GPU on just a single GPU thread (completely sequential). So I have the global thread and local thread mapping for the kernel as follows.

```
globalthread[0] = 1;
globalthread[1] = 1;

localthread[0] = 1;
localthread[1] = 1;
```

But when I compare the GPU output to the output of the same function run on the CPU
(directly and not as an opencl device) I am seeing that the outputs dont match. (the mismatch is beyond the limits of floating points accuracy).
I found this unexplainable inspite of best efforts. While trying to narrow down the problem,
I found that the problem arises from the second statement. Specifically due to the subtraction operation and when the value of A[i][j] goes negative.
I have made sure that both CPU and GPU are working on the same inputs. But such a strange behavior for such a simple computation seems weird. Can anyone help explain why the outputs might be differing?
I also ran it on both NVIDIA and AMD Devices and I see the same behavior. (to rule out any platform specific issue)

Here is the sample output of the mismatch:

```
platform name is NVIDIA CUDA
platform version is OpenCL 1.1 CUDA 4.2.1
number of devices is 2
device name is Tesla C2050 / C2070
GPU Runtime: 0.023669s
CPU Runtime: 0.000123s
Values differ at index (45, 40): arr1=0.946256, arr2=0.963078
Values differ at index (60, 52): arr1=-9.348129, arr2=-9.483719
Values differ at index (61, 52): arr1=11.343384, arr2=11.093756
Non-Matching CPU-GPU Outputs Beyond Error Threshold of 1.05 Percent: 3
```

Comment: What is the condition number of your matrix?

Comment: The condition number for 1-norm = 7.07278e+3 and for inf-norm = 5.41371e+3. So I am losing upto 3-4 digits of accuracy right? But as I understand it, condition number is a property of the matrix and not the compute device. so shouldnt the same inaccuracy come in both CPU and GPU? why do the CPU and GPU outputs mismatch? some sample mismatches are: Values differ at index (45, 40): arr1=0.946256, arr2=0.963078
Values differ at index (60, 52): arr1=-9.348129, arr2=-9.483719
Values differ at index (61, 52): arr1=11.343384, arr2=11.093756

Comment: Using double precision values solved my problem.
I guess I have an explanation: (please correct me if I am wrong).
1. Using single precision floats caused a small difference in the intermediate float point values computed between CPU and GPU.
2. Because of the high conditioning number I am losing upto 3 digits of accuracy on top of the rounding errors. This ill-conditioning caused the final result differences to be significantly high.
 
Whereas when I used double there was no rounding errors between CPU and GPU. Hence even with a ill-conditioned matrix I was able to get accurate results.

Comment: Here is a paper I came across that describes floating point accuracy issues with OpenCL.http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/jaideep/nsv12-paper.pdf